# How to export videos as real video playable files from SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, video, export

The videos are saved directly in the table in the database using asp.net. I want to export the videos as real video files, for example `.mp4`.

How can I do that? If I just export it via a script, I will get the `varbinary` data written in millions of letters, right?

I need the files like I uploaded it. I don´t need the files to play them in the web or in some application.

Thank you very much!

Comment: are you using some sort of a coded application like a webform or windows form to perform the task?

Comment: When saving the videos, asp.net is being used. And now I want to export the files from the database, just to have the files because I have lost the videos before.

Comment: you'll have to use a php script that will allow your application to download from the database again. I haven't seen it in ASP

Comment: hmm.. I want to download them manually, isn´t there any way to get the videos from the table?

Comment: you can't retrieve data from the database manually, when you upload and retrieve there is a lot of conversions that take place so you can't

Answer (score 0):

Brother may be you are asking for something like this..                          [Save Retreive and Play .MP4 files from Database](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-Save-Retrieve-and-Play-MP4-Video-files-with-live-streaming-from-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: I need the real files now for other causes, I don´t need the files for playing them in an application or in the web. The file like I uploaded it, can I get a file like that again?